# What does hinduism say about oneness of god?

Tags: vedas, gods, upanishads, brahman

What does Hinduism say about oneness of god and imagelessness of god? Doesn't it say in the vedas?

From Brahmasutra:

> Ekam Brahm, dvitiya naste neh na naste kinchan
>
> **Meaning**: there is no god but one

From Svetasvatara upanishad:

> Na Tasya Pratima Asti
>
> **Meaning**: and of that god there is no image.

Comment: सर्वं खल्विदं ब्रह्म -sarvam khalvidam brahmam

Comment: Lord is only one But he took many different forms just to get close to us. He took different form (clothing, appearance) in different religion so that people will feel close to him.

Comment: Lord is only one But he took many different forms just to get close to us.. if so then how about the people who live outside india .. he born here only .. he is god only for us indians then??

Comment: no other religion except for hinduism and some christian sects ever said that the god himself came down to earth to maintain the balance.the god himself is all powerful he can do whatever he wants within a blink of an eye why would he come .. all the other religions claim that when the earth gets corrupt he sends a prophet as for a warning to humanity before destroying them completely and the god is really furious in wrath when someone put associates with him in any form whether be an idol or some mythological names whom no one has ever seen .

Comment: @rakesh Didn't get meaning of ur first comment but on ur second comment the ques. that you raised, Same question was raised by Lord Krishan to his Guru Saṁdīpanī Muni. Krishna asked `When god can do anything by just is will then why he need to come on earth and fight demons by himself?` Then Guru replied He has to do that just to make faith in hearts of humans that there is someone who will come to protect mankind. He has to live with us and fight himself so that faith of people can be increased. Faith can't be increased if Lord does everything without coming in front of everyone

Comment: @Rakesh Lord also need to set examples by his birth stories so that people will gets inspirations from it and make themselves strong in Dharma. Let's take an example of Rama, He teaches us true dharma in his life span which no other can teach us. And Lord Krishna also gave Bhagwat Getaa which is the key of Moksha.

Comment: The vedas do not speak of incarnations. It is only in the Puranas that incarnations are spoken of.

Answer (score 8):

The Vedas clearly declare that the ultimate reality is one but we know him by different names. So, yes, oneness of Gods has been discussed in the Vedas themselves.

> Suparnam viprAh kavyo vachobhir ekam santam bahudhA kalpayanti.
>
> ..........
>
> **The wise seers describe the one existence (ekam santam) in various
>   words (bahudha vachobhih).**
>
> **Rig Veda 1.114.5.**
>
> ..............
>
> Ekam sad viprA bahudhA vadanti agnim yamam mAtrishvAnam Ahuh.
>
> ...........
>
> The sages describe **the one existence (ekam sat) in many way**s. **It is
>   called as Agni, as Yama as Matarishvan.**
>
> **Rig Veda 1.184.46.**

NOTE- Regarding the Sakara-Nirakara thing i will update this answer later.

Answer (score 5):

Yes God is one.

Swami Vivekananda:

> He is everywhere, the pure and formless One, the Almighty and the All-merciful. "Thou art our father, Thou art our mother, Thou art our beloved friend, Thou art the source of all strength; give us strength. Thou art He that beareth the burdens of the universe; help me bear the little burden of this life." Thus sang the Rishis of the Vedas. And how to worship Him? Through love. "He is to be worshipped as the one beloved, dearer than everything in this and the next life."
>
> Everything that has form must have a beginning and an end. **From Him are all name and form; all the animals and men are from Him. He is the one Supreme. He who knows Him becomes free.**

Comment: @rakesh How is idol worship related to this answer? And. Lord doesn't forbid Idol worship. Only anti Hindu organizations spread those false statements.

Comment: only you said formless??

Comment: formless itself mean no image .. no idol..

Comment: @rakesh According to Sri Ramakrishna, God is both formless and with form.

Answer (score 0):

And you will see all the major religion of the world talks bout the same think about the oneness of God. You pray directly to Him. No Image. God does not change the law everyday. He does not send different law for different tribes. Think Think. This is the most important question in life. In all religion the terms are same.

Sargh = Jannah = Heaven
Nark = Jahannam = Hell

Believing in one God without partners and no idol worship is the right path and common thread in all religions.