# What is the reference to "Ekam satyam sanatanam bahu vipra vedanti."?

Tags: reference-request

> Ekam satyam sanatanam bahu vipra vedanti.[*Rig Veda*]
>
> Existence is one (ie the soul) but ways are many .

What is the reffence to this verse. And what is the full verse.

Comment: See this: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19384/4732

Comment: @Rickross thanks for it